# How to create an instance of a class based solely on a filename (PHP)

Tags: php, model-view-controller, oop, class

I'm making a small PHP MVC framework for fun. I'm using a front controller `index.php` to route all traffic around and call new controllers as requested. However, I need a way to create an instance of a user generated controller base solely on the name of the controller (basically, the filename ie, `controllers/posts.php`).

Is there any way to do this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There are a couple ways you can do this.  One way is to establish a convention, such that the name of the class is based on the name of the file.  Another way to do it would be to parse the file for the name of the class.  Did you want to see some small code examples?

EDIT: Simple Example

Imagine we're in some core MVC controller and we want to load a controller provided by a third party user.  There are 2 things you need to do:

1. Load the file with the class definition
2. Instantiate the class

Suppose you have a convention such as Zend where class names map to the filesystem so a controller might be

`MyProject/Controller/Login.php`

for the path to the login controller, relative to the root of the project.  Following the Zend convention, the name of the class would be `MyProject_Controller_Login`.  If you want to instantiate this class all you have to do is:

```
// load class
require_once 'MyProject/Controller/Login.php';

// instantiate class
$oUserController = new MyProject_Controller_Login();
```

If you need to instantiate the class based on runtime data, you can do so with a variable that holds the name of the class, so

```
$sUserController = 'MyProject_Controller_Login';
$oUserController = new $sUserController();
```

Hopefully that's enough to get you rolling; let me know if you need more.

Comment: If you don't mind, I'd love to see some examples. I like the convention idea -- I think CodeIgniter uses that. However, how would I be able to create a new instance of a class/file in another directory?

Comment: +1, this implementation rocks. It helps keep your files organized and easy to find as well. Plus it avoids namespace collisions like a champ.

Answer (score 1):

Yes after checking within your front controller or router class that the controller file exists you can then call it:
Here is a couple of methods that I ripped from my router class that may help you, its an example but if you follow you can see how a class can be loaded and a method or action can be called:

```
<?php 
/**
* Load Class based on controller or action
*/
public function load_controller(){
    /*Get the route*/
    $this->getController();

    /*Assign front controller to handle routes that dont have core controller
    eg ./core/controllers/($this->file.Controller).php
    */
    if (is_readable($this->file) === false){
        $this->file = $this->path.'/frontController.php';
        $this->subaction = $this->action;
        $this->action = $this->controller;
        $this->controller = 'front';
    }

    /*Include core controller file*/
    include($this->file);

    /*Create controllers class instance & inject registry*/
    $className = $this->controller.'Controller';
    $controller = new $className($this->registry);

    /*Check the action method is callable within the class*/
    if (is_callable(array($controller, $this->action)) === false){
        //index() method because not found method
        $action = 'index';
    }else{
        //action() method is callable
        $action = $this->action;
    }

    /*Run the action method*/
    $controller->$action();
}

private function getController() {
    $route = (!isset($_GET['route']))?'':$this->registry->function->cleanURL($_GET['route']);
    /*Split the parts of the route*/
    $parts = explode('/', $route);
    $this->request = $route;

    $corefolders=array('core','templates');
    if (empty($route) || in_array($parts[0],$corefolders)){
        $route = 'index';
    }else{
        //Assign which controller class
        $this->controller = $parts[0];

        if(isset($parts[1])){
            /* Site.com/action */
            $this->action = $parts[1];
        }
        if(isset($parts[2])){
            /* Site.com/action/subaction */
            $this->subaction = $parts[2];
        }
    }
    /*Set controller*/
    if (empty($this->controller)){$this->controller = 'index';}
    /*Set action*/
    if (empty($this->action)){$this->action = 'index';}
    /*Set the file path*/
    $this->file = $this->path.'/'.$this->controller.'Controller.php';
}
?>
```